# Who introduced the discrete Fourier transform?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to find the original reference which introduced the definition of discrete Fourier transform as used today. When did *this modern formulation (which includes the indexing from n to N-1)* of DFT appear in the literature?

$$
\begin{aligned}
X_{k} &=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{n} \ e^{-\frac{i 2 \pi}{N} k n} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{n} \left[\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N} k n\right)-i \ \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{N} k n\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Fourier original on Analytical Theory of Heat does not deal with discrete versions. History related articles credit Gauss well before Fourier. For example here, Gauss and the History of the Fast Fourier Transform, Archive for History of Exact Sciences , 1985, Vol. 34, No. 3 (1985), pp. 265-277 ([Link])[1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133773), shows a table, but the article just defines the DFT in "modern notation" for Gauss's Latin work and credits Gauss rather.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can go earlier than Gauss if you allow for a DFT involving only sines or only cosines: I quote from [Gauss and the history of the fast Fourier transform](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226049108_Gauss_and_the_history_of_the_fast_Fourier_transform)

> Alexis-Claude Clairaut (1713-1765) published in 1754 what we currently
> believe to be the earliest explicit formula for the DFT (the
> computation for series coefficients from equally spaced samples of the
> function), but it was restricted to a cosine Fourier series. Joseph Louis Lagrange (1736-1813 published a
> DFT-like formula for finite Fourier series containing only sines, in
> 1759 and in 1762.
>
> The earliest explicit DFT formula containing both sines and cosines
> is due to Carl Friedrich Gauss (1777-1855) in *"Theoria
> Interpolationis Methodo Nova Tractata"*. It was published only
> posthumously in 1866 [10], but was originally written, most likely, in
> 1805.

Here is Gauss's formula ( [source](https://archive.org/details/werkecarlf03gausrich/page/n295/mode/2up?view=theater))

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do the primes indicate?  Is he writing $(\alpha, \alpha', \alpha'', \alpha''', \dotsc)$ in place of $(\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \dotsc)$?

Comment: yes, you can see that the $m$-th term is denoted $\alpha^m$ and $\beta^m$.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, I am also interested in the earliest appearance og modern discrete representation and notation.

Comment: Ah, I [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417034/who-introduced-the-discrete-fourier-transform/417045#comment1070234_417045).  I didn't zoom in and thought that the $m$s were triple primes.

Comment: @M.Farooq, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417034/who-introduced-the-discrete-fourier-transform/417045#comment1070236_417045), your definition of "modern notation" seems compatible with this answer, except for the difference of indexing and the explicit appearance of the $\sum$ operator.  Are you looking for the first place that the equation appears exactly as you have written it?

Comment: @LSpice, Yes you are right, but who proposed this indexing from 0 to N-1 and summation in this modern DFT representation?

Comment: 0 to N-1 doesn't feel all that modern when it's really Z/NZ (if not an abstract cyclic group of order N without a choice of generator).